# Why doesn't $f_n(x)=(n^2x^2)/\left(1+x^2\right)^n$ verify $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n = \int\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n$?

Tags: integration, limits, lebesgue-integral

The question is:
If $f_n(x)=\dfrac{n^2x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^n}$, with $x\in [0,1]$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\int\limits^{\cssId{upper-bound-mathjax}{1}}_{\cssId{lower-bound-mathjax}{0}} \dfrac{n^2x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^n}\,\cssId{int-var-mathjax}{\mathrm{d}x} \neq \displaystyle\int\limits^{\cssId{upper-bound-mathjax}{1}}_{\cssId{lower-bound-mathjax}{0}}\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n^2x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^n}\,\cssId{int-var-mathjax}{\mathrm{d}x}$$

The problem gives a hint: try to find a lower bound for $f_n$ in $[0,\frac{1}{\sqrt n}]$.

Thanks.

Comment: The hint is for LHS. Fo RHS, the pointwise limit is trivially 0, so the intergal of the limit is 0.

Comment: Thanks! That's useful, so you mean i have to find a lower bound to $f_n$ to integrate it and prove it is higher than 0?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've edited the title, hope it's a bit better now.

Comment: @shaun editing is good, but refrain from using dfrac  in titles, try to keep vertical extension of titles small.

Comment: The title seems to say the opposite of the question?

Comment: Ok, i'll change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0\leqslant x\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt n}$, then$$(1+x^2)^n\leqslant\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\leqslant3$$and therefore\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{n^2x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\,\mathrm dx&\geqslant\int_0^{1/\sqrt n}\frac{n^2x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\,\mathrm dx\\&\geqslant\frac13\int_0^{1/\sqrt n}n^2x^2\,\mathrm dx\\&=\frac{\sqrt n}9.\end{align}So,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{n^2x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\,\mathrm dx=\infty.$$But, for each $x\in(0,1]$,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}=0.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, now i see it very clear.

Answer (score 2):

We can try to find a similar limit. We have that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{n^2x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\:dx \geq \int_0^1 \frac{n^{\frac{3}{2}}x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\:dx$$

for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$. For the integral on the right, use the substitution $u = \sqrt{n}x$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\sqrt{n}}\frac{u^2}{\left(1+\frac{u^2}{n}\right)^n}\:du \longrightarrow \int_0^\infty u^2e^{-u^2}\:du = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}$$

by dominated convergence. Thus we have that while the right hand side goes to $0$, the left hand side is larger than a positive number (in fact it even grows without bound).

Comment: I'm not convinced that justifying a $\lim$ and $\int$ swap by another swap using dominated convergence theorem is wise. This is true of course, but this is a case of using an overpowerful tool to solve a simple problem solvable by just inequality.